# Meteor App get value of textarea in form

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor, text, textarea

I am writing a little Meteor app. There is a textarea in a form, which looks like this:

```
<form name="comments-form">
    <label for="textarea">Comment:</label><br>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="comment_textarea" class="comment_textarea">Write your comment here.</textarea><br>
    <button class="btn btn-success js-add-comment">add comment</button>
</form>
```

In my `client.js` I have the following code for accessing the value of the textarea:

```
EVENT_HANDLED = false;

Template.website_item_details.events({
    "click .js-add-comment": function(event) {
        var comment_text = event.target.comment_textarea.value;

        if(Meteor.user()) {
            Comments.insert({
                created_by: Meteor.user()._id,
                text: comment_text,
                website_id: this._id
            });
        }

        return EVENT_HANDLED;
    }
});
```

However, when I click the button to add the comment, I get the following console output:

```
TypeError: event.target.comment_textarea is undefined
["click .js-add-comment"]()
 client.js:103
Template.prototype.events/eventMap2[k]</</<()
 blaze.js:3697
Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc()
 blaze.js:3671
Template.prototype.events/eventMap2[k]</<()
 blaze.js:3696
attached_eventMaps/</</</<()
 blaze.js:2557
Blaze._withCurrentView()
 blaze.js:2211
attached_eventMaps/</</<()
 blaze.js:2556
HandlerRec/this.delegatedHandler</<()
 blaze.js:833
jQuery.event.dispatch()
 jquery.js:4690
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle()
```

This seems to be basic form handling, but somehow I can't get that text in the textarea into a variable in my javascript code. I've already tried a multitude of variants of accessing it:

```
document.getElementsByClass()[0].value
$('.comment_textarea').get(0).val()  // there should only be one such text area anyway
event.target.comment_textarea.value;
```

But none of those work for me, I always get that error. It's almost like the textarea was not part of my `html` or there is a bug in Meteor, which prevents me from accessing textareas.

I also checked whether there are other things named `comment_textarea` with a fulltext search on all of my projects clientside files, but there isn't any other.

Am I simply blind and overlooking something? How do I get that text?

What's more is, that although I return `false`, the browser still reloads the page. Could it be related to the error happening before?

Comment: I don't know what 'Meteor' does but your textarea has no class name and no id. Could be that the issue?

Comment: @Franco Ah I changed the code of that so many times, but there was a class name when I tried the class thingy : )

Comment: Ok I was just wondering. I have never used 'Meteor' and this was the first thing which have get my attention.

Comment: @Franco I edited the question, for completeness sake, thanks for pointing it out. Others might have thought that it is an issue with the missing class, if you didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `click` event of the button and on that event, the `textarea` is not available. You need to change the event into `submit form`. First, put the id into your form, change the button into type `submit` and change the code into

```
"submit #your-form-id": function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var comment_text = event.target.comment_textarea.value;
    .....

}
```

Comment: This showed me the underlying issue. I didn't have to give the button element the type submit, but the explanation why it didn't work as I planned it to it important. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After trying even more desperate ways to access that textarea, I think I know now what's wrong:

```
// var comment_text = event.target.comment_textarea.value;
// var comment_text = document.getElementByName('comment_textarea').value;
// var comment_text = document.getElementByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
// var comment_text = $('textarea').get(0).val();
// var comment_text = $('textarea').get(0).text();
var comment_text = $('textarea').get(0).value;  // finally working!
```

So it seems that when I use jQuery, I can't use the `.val()` function as stated in my other answers to many other questions, but for some reason I have to treat it like a normal DOM object and use the attribute `value` instead of the function `.val()`.

Maybe it's specific to the jQuery version in my Meteor app?

So I will test the following:

```
var comment_text = $('textarea.comment_textarea').get(0).value;
```

...
Yes, that also works.
Also it fixes the reload issue. I guess since there was an error, it didn't even get to return false and this is why the website reloaded.